# SharePoint <button> elements perform an unwanted reload of the page

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an aspx page on my SharePoint site, which I have included  tags. For some reason, every button on the page will reload the page when clicked. Even the buttons with no attributes (id, class, etc) or functions will reload the page when clicked. How can I fix this issue? I can't even see what's going on in the debugger because I'm not calling any reload functions, so I have no idea where to place a breakpoint.

Thank you in advance for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: How did you put the buttons on the page? Do they have `runat="server"` or maybe are they `<asp:Button` buttons?

Comment: The buttons themselves are only <button>CLICK ME</button> (I removed everything interesting from my code to make sure that wasn't causing the problem. However, my buttons are between <asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain"> 
</asp:Content>
 tags.

Answer (score 15):

The problem here is with the <button> tag.  Its default behavior is to act as a submit button unless otherwise declared and will reload.

To keep your <button> tag, add type='button' to the button element.  I think that prevents the reload.

Or you could go with the ole <input> tag with a type='button'.  That keeps the reload from happening as well.

Or some other html element with an onclick event will work too.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark my response as the answer.

Comment: Hi @Josey, unfortunately I'm not the person who made the answer or I don't have enough privileges to do this

Comment: @Josey same issue with <input type="input"> tag when onMouseDown event gets triggered on press of "Enter". any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

First search for a function called doPostback and set a breakpoint on the entry point and click a button.  If you hit this breakpoint it could mean that auto post back is turned on for the control generating the button.  However if you trigger that breakpoint you should be able to look at the stack trace to figure out how you got there.

If that doesn't work, use the F12 tools in the browser, start with the HTML section and search (Ctrl-F) for the word "click".  Then go to the script tab and do the same for each JavaScript file.  If all of the buttons exhibit the behavior there is most likely a click event registered.  Possibly with jQuery that looks like this $('button') so that it matches all buttons on the page and registers a click handler.

If that doesn't find it, and you have access download one of the master pages from http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/ and temporarily replace your master page with one of these.  Take a screenshot of the scripts that are loading on your page first.  Then add them to the starter master page one at a time until the unwanted behavior returns.  Then set a breakpoint on every function entry point in that script and click a button and see where you land.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it is extremely helpful. I had no idea where to start, but this at least gets me in the right direction. Unfortunately, after trying the last suggestion (looking at JavaScript files one at a time to find the root of the problem), it seems that the issue may be be coming from a quirk in some SharePoint code. Still trying to figure out what's causing it.

Comment: I used Google Chrome's debugger's event listener to place a breakpoint on the 'click' event. This caused the function to stop inside of a SharePoint JavaScript file. The .js file has a very complicated name, but the comments toward the top of the file is MicrosoftAjax.js, so I assume that's what it really is. The file only has 3 long lines of code (so the function is all on one long line and I'm not sure how to debug that), and the Call Stack only shows the MouseEvent itself.