# Loading Bot using DirectLine in SharePoint - builder.prompts.choice button refresh issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, botframework, azure-language-understanding

When loading my bot using BotChat.js directline connection to Bot Framework inside of a SharePoint page, any builder.prompts.choice options that contain builder.liststyle.button will cause a page refresh if a user clicks that option.

HTML Button returned from BotChat.js DirectLine channel

```
<button class="ac-pushButton" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; flex: 0 1 auto;">Test Button</button>
```

This appears to be down to the HTML button being returned to the user not having a type="button" attribute ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846211/sharepoint-button-elements-perform-an-unwanted-reload-of-the-page)).

How could I go about loading this attribute in to buttons that are displayed in the Bot Chat?